# Partially transparent images in javafx

Tags: java, javafx, png, desktop-application, scenebuilder

I am making a project in eclipse. I have uploaded a .png file using 'image view' option.It has some transparent areas .I want to write code such that it only detects the click of the user's mouse when it is over opaque area and take that user to a new window defined by me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should work in most circumstances.

```
imageView.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, e -> {
    Color color = image.getPixelReader().getColor(e.getX(),e.getY()));
    if(color.getAlpha() != 0)
    {
        //execute your code here
    }
});
```

Comment: @mistletoe Accepting my answer would be great.